# How to execute multiple commands on linux server through bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, cicd

I am trying to create a bitbucket pipeline in which I need to create a backup of my deployed build.

My current bitbucket-pipelines.yml file looks like this

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: 'Deployment and Backup to Staging'
        deployment: staging
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.8.0
            variables:
              SSH_USER: 'ubuntu'
              SERVER: $HOST
              COMMAND: 'echo $HOSTNAME;
                cd ~/workspace;
                DATE=$(date +"%y%m%d");
                BACKUP_NAME="test-bak-$DATE";
                echo "Creating backup $BACKUP_NAME";
                rm -rf test-bak-* ; # Remove existing backup directories
                cp -r portals "$BACKUP_NAME"; # Create a backup with the current date'
```

So here I am trying to create a current date variable "DATE" and use it to name my backup name "BACKUP_NAME" and then I am deleting any previous backup directory and then copying the current deployed version into my backup name

The problem which is coming is that BACKUP_NAME variable coming as empty string because my echo is only printing "Creating backup" and not this "Creating backup test-bak-310124" and also I checked on my server there is no copy of my portals directory with the backup name

Can anyone help over here ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to try 'mv' without quotes:

```
mv portals $BACKUP_NAME


$ ls
portals  test-bak-240131
$ DATE=$(date +"%y%m%d")
$ BACKUP_NAME="test-bak-$DATE"
$ echo $BACKUP_NAME
test-bak-240131
$ rm -rf test-bak-*/
$ ls
portals
$ mv portals $BACKUP_NAME
$ ls
test-bak-240131
```